# Custom Field on Settings page

Tags: custom-field

I would like to have a custom field on the general settings page where I can enter the meta description for the website. Can this be achieved somehow?

Another way I could think of is to add such a field to a section, the homepage for example, but this solution wouldn't be elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t change or add fields to the General Settings page, but for site wide available content Craft has this concept of Globals.

See the documentation on it:
https://craftcms.com/docs/globals

It’s also very easy to manage user permissions for Globals, so you can allow certain user groups (besides admins) to change the meta data, somthing that (currently) isn’t possible for everything in Settings.

Comment: I didn't know about Globals - it's a great solution. Thank you